# Java MC Plugin ProtocolLib Mute Pistons Sounds

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

so currently I have this code:

```
@Override

public void onEnable(){

    ProtocolManager manager = ProtocolLibrary.getProtocolManager();
    manager.addPacketListener(
            new PacketAdapter(this, ListenerPriority.HIGHEST,
                    PacketType.Play.Server.NAMED_SOUND_EFFECT) {
                @Override
                public void onPacketSending(PacketEvent event) {
                    // Item packets (id: 0x29)
                    if (event.getPacketType() ==
                            PacketType.Play.Server.NAMED_SOUND_EFFECT) {
                        if (packet.getSoundEffetcs().getValues().contains(Sound.BLOCK_PISTON_CONTRACT || packet.getSoundEffetcs().getValues().contains(Sound.BLOCK_PISTON_EXTEND))){

                        }

                        event.setCancelled(true);
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    // Plugin shutdown logic
}
```

}

It is not complete, once its finished it should cancel all the
packets that get send to the server/client in which piston sounds get involved.
The code `if (packet.getSoundEffetcs().getValues().contains(Sound.BLOCK_PISTON_CONTRACT || packet.getSoundEffetcs().getValues().contains(Sound.BLOCK_PISTON_EXTEND)))`
is providing me trouble because the "**packet**.getSoundEffects()" tells me that it "cant resolve symbol "packet"" as an Error. Which imports to I have to add to my Plugin so that "packet" gets recognized properly?

Answer (score 0):

You never define the `packet` variable.

You have to do it like that :

```java
@Override
public void onPacketSending(PacketEvent event) {
    // Item packets (id: 0x29)
    if (event.getPacketType() == PacketType.Play.Server.NAMED_SOUND_EFFECT) {
        PacketContainer packet = event.getPacket(); // get ProtocolLib packet
        List<Sound> sounds = packet.getSoundEffetcs().getValues(); // get values from it
        if (sounds.contains(Sound.BLOCK_PISTON_CONTRACT || sounds.contains(Sound.BLOCK_PISTON_EXTEND))){
             // here what you want
        }
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```